# Preventing visual studio removing carriage returns in cshtml while formatting code

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010, razor, formatting

When I try to format code of cshtml document with visual studio, a lot of carriage returns are deleted.

As example, this code:

```
  <div class="float-left">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate)
  </div>

  <div class="float-left" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px; margin-right: 30px;">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate)
  </div>
```

Is changed to this when I do the format command of visual studio:

```
<div class="float-left">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate)
  </div>
  <div class="float-left" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px; margin-right: 30px;">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate)
  </div>
```

Note that there is no more empty line between the two divs.

Is it possible to prevent visual studio removing the carriage returns?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under `Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Formatting`, there is a button labeled `Tag Specific Options...`  Here you will find many options for HTML tags and ASP.NET Controls.  Since Razor is just HTML with some extra syntax sugar, the HTML settings should govern the formatting.

For example, under `Client HTML Tags`, if you set `div` to have `2 Before opening, within, and 2 after closing` for `Line Breaks`, I think this will give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you @Sumo! Very nice option but do you think it's possible to preventing visual studio handle all carriage returns formatting; I just want the ability of visual studio to indent and insert spaces but without adding or removing carriage returns?

Comment: Instead of `2 Before opening...` setting, try `None` to see if it leaves your line feed formatting alone.  I always use JetBrain's ReShaper's settings, which are more sophisticated.